# R dataframe select distinct list of value per group

Tags: r, group-by, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe that consists of 2 columns:

```
> head(session_item_pairs)
    session_id      item_id
53         811 111502665618
78         841 111502665618
127        901 111502665618
151        931 111502665618
477       1351 111502665618
501       1351 115641561585
```

I need to group the dataframe by session_id and for each session_id return the list of unique items in ascending order for that session_id. e.g. for session_id 1351 the result will be

```
1351 (111502665618,115641561585)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Your example data contains only unique entries per session_id and the expected output doesn't match the input. You can try a dplyr solution like this: `library(dplyr); DF %>% distinct(session_id, item_id) %>% arrange(session_id, item_id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `split` then `unique` functions.

```
grouped <- split(df$item_id, df$session_id)
unique_items <- lapply(grouped, unique)
```

or in one line

```
lapply(split(df$item_id, df$session_id), unique)
```

To `sort` the results:

```
lapply(split(df$item_id, df$session_id), function(x) sort(unique(x)) )
```

Comment: Here's a tidyverse solution: 

df %>% group_by(session_id) %>%
  summarise(item_ids = list(sort(unique(item_id))))